# "Does Not Contain" text filter filters too much

Tags: excel, powerquery

By using Power Query, I have created an address list from address fields in approx. 15000 individual excel files.

I now have a list with 15143 rows but I have run into problems with the "Does Not Contain" Text filter.

I want to keep rows that do not contain the search term "foo" in a specific column.

When I first use the "Contains" "foo" Text Filter it returns a list of 150 rows

But when I use the "**Does Not** Contain" "foo" Text Filter instead the list is shortened to only 3218 rows.

A bit unexpected result...

If I recall my maths lessons correctly 15143-150=14993, not 3218.

This is driving me nuts!

Do I do something wrong or is it the Almighty Microsoft Bug that has hit me, once again?

Comment: My bet is that the column you're filtering has lots of blanks, and the "does not contain" filter is excluding those. Can you do countifs(C:C,"") (or whatever your column is) to see how many cells are blank?

Comment: Thanks @WillJobs! You were spot on! 11775 of the cells were blank!

Comment: I solved the problem by first extracting the list using PQ and saving it as a separate excel file. Then I added the file as a PQ data source in a new document and did the rest of the filtering and processing from there. Then I was able to do the desired "Does Not Contain" filtering without problems. Do you know why that worked when it didn't work in the first way? @WillJobs?

Comment: @MrDark you can also use `Table.SelectRows(YourTable, each Text.Contains([FieldName], "SearchString") = false or [FieldName] = "")` clause

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This behavior is related to the expected Sql logic for null: if a row field is null, it doesn't contain "foo" but it also doesn't not contain "foo". Put differently, a WHERE filter skips rows that evaluate to null, and `not null` is also null.

You can see this in Power Query:

```
let
    Source = Table.FromColumns({{null, "foo", "bar"}}),
    FilteredRows = Table.SelectRows(Source, each 
        not Text.Contains([Column1], "foo") or Text.Contains([Column1], "foo"))
in
    FilteredRows
```

... only returns the last two rows.

In Power Query if you want to avoid this bizarre kind of logic, you can replace null with empty string and then you get nicer behavior:

```
= Table.ReplaceValue(Source,null,"",Replacer.ReplaceValue,{"Column1"})
```

Comment: That makes sense! Thanks @carl for your explanation of this seemingly strange behavior.